# Timeline threads are not displayed in Threads tab of VisualVM 1.3.9

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, visualvm

In VisualVM 1.3.9 with Eclipse on a Windows 7 x64 machine we run a threaded application. But we cannot see the timeline of the threads although we ensure that there are living threads. There is an image attached below to describe the situation.

How can we see the threads in that timeline?

PS: The VisualVM in JDK is also response as same way.

PS2: Timeline is displayed in Netbeans' VisualVM.

[VisualVM 1.3.9 Threads image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H89CN.jpg)

[image]

--
Best Regards